# Model-View-Controller(Presenter) workflow in a desktop application using Java and JavaFx

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, workflow, mvp

I am implementing an application that works with images and applies filters on them. The back-end is written on Java and it has attached a desktop app made with JavaFx and FXML. The problem that I encountered is how I could organize my code the best way possible.

I have one Controller that is in charge with the functionality of the elements defined in the fxml file and a Model where, for the moment is the entire java based logic from the back-end. But isn't the Model supposed to contain domain objects like POJO classes? Where should I put the method that take the image as a parameter and do the filtering stuff, the method that should be called by the Controller when a button is clicked?

I thought of adding a Service package that will have classes that will implement this logic, and this one should call methods from Model?
Or should they be in Model but just in different class?

An advice will be much appreciated :) Also is this kind of architecture more like an MVP than an MVC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned to structure my JavaFX projects in MVC pattern. I learned through following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17uSUxhRQ80), Almas walks you through building a simple text editor while applying the MVC design pattern.

[JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) was also extremely useful to when I started styling using CSS.

Also note when styling some node components in CSS there may be a number of layers for example:

```
#boldSeparator .line {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1 1 1 1;
}
```

Another example makes the arrow in ChoiceBox appear invisible:

```
choice-box, .choice-box .arrow, .choice-box .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know I can add CSS styles, but my question has nothing to do with the View layer. I was wondering if it would be a good solution to make a layer in between Model and Controller( let's call it Service). Controller should have access to the Service layer, but I am not sure if Controller should also have access to Model, or only the Service should(have access to Model).  I might just complicate myself, but I don't know why this seems more logical to me.

Comment: What would be the purpose of Service?

Comment: Depending what you mean by Model. I might be wrong, but I always thought of the Model layer being like simple classes, not including classes that manage lists (like a repository, for example, in a domain-repository-controller-ui structure). I always resemble the Model layer from MVC with domain from the above specified architecture. Am I mistaken?